# Can't download zip file from server for android 10 API 29

Tags: android, android-10.0

I'm unable to download a zip folder from server for android 10 API 29. It is working fine for versions lower than API 29. I'm also using a 3rd party pdf reader library called MuPDF.

Two lines of error which caught my eyes are:

```
2019-09-25 17:55:52.198 9520-9593/com.smedia.wrapper E/IOException: No such file or directory
2019-09-25 17:55:54.084 619-9594/? E/ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (100, <unspecified>/0)
```

Does anybody else is facing this issue? Am I missing something? Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: android 10 uses a different file access system
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped

Comment: WOW! That really helped, thanks man. You can post answer below if you want, I can upvote it. :)